# How to return an array in ctyps when calling a function

Tags: python, c, arrays, pointers, ctypes

What I want to do is to convert a C function into python function.

For example, I have a C function prototype which is pre-defined:

```
function_test(ViInt32 Arraysize, ViReal64 readingArray[], ViInt32 *Actual_rraysize)
```

The input of the above function is `Arraysize`, which is the number of elements in the `readingArray` parameter.

The outputs of the above function are `readingArray[]` and `Arraysize`. `readingArray[]` returns an array of the result and `Actual_arraysize` indicates the actual size of the returned array.

And the following is the Python function I wrote by using this C function prototype:

```
from ctypes import *
def Py_function_test(self, arraysize, readingarray = [], actualarraysize = [-1e-10]):
    while len(readingarray) < arraysize:
        readingarray.append(0)
    _c_actualarraysize = c_int()
    ArrayOfDouble = c_double * arraysize
    _c_readingarray = ArrayOfDouble()
    self.function_test(c_int(arraysize), 
                       byref(_c_readingarray), 
                       byref(_actualarraysize))
    for n in range(arraysize):
        readingarray[n] = _c_readingarray[n]
    actualarraysize[0] = _c_actualarraysize.value
```

In the end, it turned out the value of `acutalarraysize` is successfully changed. But the value of `readingarray` didn't change after calling the `c function prototype`.

How to deal with this situation, is it because I should not have used the `byref`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you don't need byref when passing array. And using list as default argument values will cause unexpected bugs. You can return the array and the actualarrysize in your Python function.

Here is my code:

```
from ctypes import *
test = cdll.LoadLibrary("test")
test.function_test.argtypes = [
    c_int, POINTER(c_double), POINTER(c_int)
]

def Py_function_test(arraysize):
    _c_readingarray = (c_double*arraysize)()
    _c_actualarraysize = c_int()
    test.function_test(arraysize, _c_readingarray, byref(_c_actualarraysize))
    return _c_readingarray, _c_actualarraysize.value

array, size = Py_function_test(10)
print list(array), size
```

the c code:

```
void function_test(int Arraysize, double readingArray[], int *Actual_rraysize)
{
    int i;
    *Actual_rraysize = Arraysize/2;
    for(i=0;i<*Actual_rraysize;i++)
        readingArray[i] = i;
}
```

and the output of python code is:

```
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] 5
```

Comment: I don't know what is the problem, but after I tried your method, the value of `_c_readingarray` still doesn't change.

Comment: Are you sure the c function change the content of readingArray? I added the test c code. Please compile the c code into test.dll and try my python code.

Comment: Thanks very much, finally I find out what is the problem. It's the problem with the `dll` but not the python implementation, but what you taught me was very useful for me.